# Is there a keyboard shortcut in Google Sheets to append cell content, not replace it when writing something new?

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

When a cell is selected in Google Sheets, and I start to type a new text, the old is replaced content is replaced by a new one. Can I somehow select the cell in a way that if I type something new, it will append previous content, not delete it?

I have checked shortcuts [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), but I haven't found what I am looking for.

Comment: You can select the cell and then press `F2` to edit the cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the cell and then press `F2` to edit the cell.

Oddly enough, I searched through that help document you linked to and I do not see that shortcut. I wonder why that is?